# integral with several answers

Tags: indefinite-integrals

Could you help me please with a question about integrals? Can an integral have more than one answer? For example with this integral: 
$$\int\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$
Doing by replacing u=$\sqrt{1-x^2}$, I have this solution: 
$$2\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}-\frac23 \left(1-\sqrt{1-x^2} \right)^{3/2},$$
and another solution doing by replacing $\sin \theta =x/1$, I get:
$$2\sqrt{2} \sin(\arcsin(x/2))-\frac43 \sqrt{2} \sin^3(\arcsin(x/2))).$$
The graph of each one is in this picture:
[image]
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this $$\int\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$?

Comment: Yes, could you help me please

Comment: In your question the argument of $\arcsin$ is $x/2$. In the Geogebra plot is $x$. Which one is the result you obtain?

Comment: Sorry. the correct one is the one in geogebra

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error in one of your solutions lies in the fact that you have to consider the sign of the $x$ values used when performing the integration. In particular, using $u=\sqrt{1-x^2}$, we cannot say that $x=\sqrt{1-u^2}$ because $x$ may be negative whereas the square root term cannot. Also I believe you forgot to use the fact that $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$ in your working. The trigonometric substitution has given you the correct answer for the integral in the interval $x\in[-1,1]$. We can get the correct algebraic solution by using the identity
$$\sin{\left(\frac{\arcsin{(x)}}2\right)}=\text{sgn}(x)\sqrt{\frac{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}2}$$
for $x\in[-1,1]$. Here $\text{sgn}(x)$ denotes the [Sign function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function). This gives the value of the integral as
$$2\text{sgn}(x)\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}-\frac23\text{sgn}(x) (1-\sqrt{1-x^2})^{3/2}+C$$
instead of your solution. The two answers are then the exact same function.

Comment: Thank you friend, the answer you give graphically are the same with the first one in geogebra, the doubt I have is if the graph doesn't matter. Thank you.

Comment: But if I remove the sign function of the answer it is equal to the second one graph. Then should I remove the sign function or not?, or what answer is the correct one . Thank you

Comment: You require the sign function for the correct value of the integral. You made an error when calculating the integral for the first time as you did not consider it.

Comment: Ok, Thank you so much my friend.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, an integral can be have more than one "answer", hence the importance of the constant that is added when finished integrating. More correctly, if two functions $f$ and $g$ they have the same derivative, so we can say that these differ by a constant :
$$f'=g' \, \Rightarrow \, f=g+c \, \textrm{ for some } c$$
Think of a simpler example, let
$$\int 2 \sin x \cos x \ dx$$
then, if we take $u=\sin x$, this integral is equal to $\sin^2 x$ and if we take $u=\cos x$ the integral is $-\cos^2 x$.

As you can see, the integral has two (or more) answers, and that clearly $\sin^2 x \neq -\cos^2 x$.

In fact, this two functions differ by a constant, by $1$ :
$$\sin^2 x = -\cos^2 x \color{red}{+1}$$

Comment: The plot of OP shows the functions don't differ by a constant..

Comment: Surely there is an error in the calculation of the antiderivative. And also, the function in Geogebra is misspelled, it is different from what he wrote in his question.

Comment: That's the reason of my comment, as a matter of fact.

Comment: Why the downvote? I answered the initial OP question.

Comment: I didn't downvote... And it is not me that posted the question, actually.